# How to deal with passwords, API keys, etc in development stack? (git, webservers, etc)

Tags: php, git, security, passwords, secret-key

I'm planning a large PHP project for a commercial website dealing with Bitcoin-related services. This will be an attractive target for hackers.

Besides making the site itself as secure as possible, I'm also wrapping my head around things like: database logins and passwords, public + private keys, secret authentication keys for remote APIs or external services, SSH keys, Bitcoin wallets, etc.

Obviously I need them somewhere within my PHP sources. I usually put all secret or sensitive details in a separate include file (e.g. 'passwords.php'), which I place outside of the HTTP document root. So visitors can never directly access the file itself.

But there's more:

1. What about the hosting provider? Of course I have to trust them if I'm hosting my server with them in the first place, but is there anything I can do to lower the risk of some employee abusing risky stuff such as Bitcoin exchange API keys?
2. Git repositories: especially if we are to host git reposities remotely, should I keep the passwords.php file completely out of the git repository, to make sure the data doesn't leak anywhere? (but then how do I go about version control or distribute it to team members?)
3. Strict communication policies: I will be working with multiple people, and I want to avoid anyone ever emailing or plain-FTP'ing these sensitive details. Some people will only need access to a testing environment, not the actual production server. How do I restrict access to passwords.php (containing actual server logins etc) only to those who really need it?

I have no clear idea yet exactly how to tackle these issues. Would anyone have some suggestions, or an indication how to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like quite an undertaking. Lots of risk involved. But props for going after your goal.

As for security, I'm no expert, but your best best would probably be heavy encryption. Beyond that, I think there will always be vulnerabilities to face when dealing with external sources such as ISPs and hosting providers. You just can't think like that, and if you can't help it, you need to find a new host.

I would suggest hosting your application using Amazon Web Services. They provide easy to manage, secure, reliable web services. Once you start segmenting your application out (db servers, cache clusters, media servers, etc) it will become less of 'I hope I don't get hacked' and more of 'I hope I can manage all this crap by myself!'.

I suggest you seek a seasoned full stack developer, or even a small team, with an emphasis on security and encryption. With all the MtGox stuff that went down you are treading down a very serious road, so be very cautious and diligent. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do you mean heavy encryption, encrypting what? They have to be in my PHP files one way or another, and the runtime environment will need to read the passwords and API keys at some point and use them. As for the hosting solution - now that you mention the MtGox example, I wonder how current exchanges (e.g. kraken or bitstamp) are taking care of their hosting, and more importantly, their data security? With hundreds of millions of dollars on the line, I'd say even the smallest risk or exploit opportunity is a disaster waiting to happen...?